# How to achieve crawling web and waiting for specific event?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm now making a bot, using selenium, crawling a website that is protected by captcha. I plan to first get to the page where the captcha exists, then send a post request which containing the text captcha in base64 form to 2captcha to crack it. Finally, 2captcha will send the answer in post request to a url I specified, after handleing the incoming result the crawler could type in the text and pass the captcha challenge.

What I'm confusing is the part how to send the answer, gotten from 2captcha, back to the crawler, also making the crawler waiting for it.

I had built a LAMP server to test it, but stuck on the part of sending data back to crawler.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

you should use EC.* of selenium to wait for something happen
you click and html reload, then some element can be located
like login or logout some website, you should wait until page reload and some element can be located.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, r"")))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, r"")))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, r"")))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.title_contains((By.XPATH, r"")))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, r"")))
```